# How do plugin goals tie into build phases in maven

Tags: maven

How do plugins add to build phases.

I realize that maven has a list of goals that it executes by default but when we add a plugin node to the
pom.xml,

For example, as per the maven documentation if we include the following plugin

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.modello</groupId>
   <artifactId>modello-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <configuration>
         <models>
           <model>src/main/mdo/maven.mdo</model>
         </models>
         <version>4.0.0</version>
       </configuration>
       <goals>
         <goal>java</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Q1. What build phase does it tie into by default ?

Q2. Does it get executed in addition to the 'default' goal?, for example if i have a plugin that just echos 'hello'
    and it gets tied to the compile phase, do i get a echo of 'hello' in addition to the compilation?

Thanks
Venu

Comment: About which `default` goal are you talking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see that in the documentation of the [plugin](http://modello.codehaus.org/modello-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) which says the java goal is bound to `generate-sources`.

What you are talking about `default` goal does not exist. It makes more sense in the meaning of a default binding between maven-plugin:goal and the life-cycle phase in relationship with the packaging type of a project. There you have a kind of default binding which is defined in the [Maven super pom](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM) which defines the goals and their execution in the life-cyclce.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Also about my second question. Is it an append to the default goals or a replace?

Comment: Enhanced my answer in accordance with your second question.